# Jquery Event Firing wrong. Need Closure?

Tags: jquery, closures, this, mouseenter, mouseleave

My function is triggering the second `mouseleave()` event rather than the first one, resulting in `nth-child(1)` & `nth-child(2)` to have a .css property of `bottom:99px` when i want them to use the first `mouseleave()` event which sets the property to `bottom:94px`

I am fairly sure after some research that i need to close my (this) statement so that when i call it in for the second round of arguments it works within the new scope..?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#rows').on('mouseenter', "div.row div:nth-child(1), div.row div:nth-child(2)",this , function() {
        $('img',this).stop().animate({"bottom":"0px"}, "fast"); 
    });

    $('div',this).off("mouseleave").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $('img',this).stop().animate({"bottom":"94px"}, "fast");    
    }); 

// need closure here? 

    $('#rows').on('mouseenter', "div.row div:nth-child(3), div.row div:nth-child(4)",this , function() {
        $('img',this).stop().animate({"bottom":"0px"}, "fast"); 
    });

    $('div',this).off("mouseleave").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $('img',this).stop().animate({"bottom":"99px"}, "fast");    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you want this:

```
$('#rows').on('mouseenter', "div.row div:nth-child(1), div.row div:nth-child(2)", this , function() {
    $('img', this).stop().animate({"bottom":"0px"}, "fast");

    // when placed inside, the value of this makes more sense?
    $('div', this).off("mouseleave").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $('img',this).stop().animate({"bottom":"94px"}, "fast");    
    }); 
});
```

In this statement that you wrote, the value of `this` is probably `window`, so `$('div', this)` would target all div on the page.

```
$('div', this).off("mouseleave").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $('img',this).stop().animate({"bottom":"94px"}, "fast");    
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jack!!! That makes sense, thank you for taking a look at my problem, bless!!

Comment: instead of ('div', this) i am just using (this) and it works now within the confins of the function :)

Comment: This is very inefficient, since it's removing and re-attaching the `mouseleave` listener everytime there's a `mouseenter` event.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps the following is what you need.  This code is untested, but it'll at least give you the gist:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

  var rows, selector, listeners = {};

  rows = $( '#rows' );

  listeners.mouseenter = function () {

    $( 'img', this ).stop().animate( { "bottom" : "0px" }, "fast" );

  };


  listeners.mouseleave = function ( event ) {

    $( 'img', this ).stop().animate(

      { "bottom" : event.data.bottom + "px" }, "fast"

    );

  };


  selector = "div.row div:nth-child(1), div.row div:nth-child(2)";

  rows.on( 'mouseenter', selector, listeners.mouseenter );

  rows.off( 'mouseleave', selector );

  rows.on( 'mouseleave', selector, { bottom : 94 }, listeners.mouseleave );


  selector = "div.row div:nth-child(3), div.row div:nth-child(4)";

  rows.on( 'mouseenter', selector, listeners.mouseenter );

  rows.off( 'mouseleave', selector );

  rows.on( 'mouseleave', selector, { bottom : 99 }, listeners.mouseleave );

} );
```

In this case, inside the handlers `this` will be the elements matching the selectors (nth-child `div` of `div.row`).